# how do I swap a cell in a column to another cell in another column for every nth row

Tags: excel

```
This is what I have:  This is what I want:
       A   B   C            A   B   C
    1  b   ab               ab  ab  
    2  x   x                x   x
    3  c   ac               ac  ac
```

And there are several hundred rows below. What I need is to replace the content of column A with the content of Column B for every nth row

Comment: To do this in place will require vba.  Have you tried any code?  Break down the steps into a logical sequence, google each step and try to combine the steps.

Comment: I have never used vba, is it included in Excel?

Comment: It is the coding applicable to excel.  It is included in excel.  You will need to familiarize yourself with the code and how to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how complex your data are, but here's a hacky method as long as "nth" is consistent and you don't mind duplicating your data into another sheet or columns.

For example, let's say you want to replace the value for every 4th row, starting with the first row of data.

Add a column to your original data (in this case, I'm calling it "whatever"), then start numbering your rows as 4, 5, 6, etc.

Create a column for your new "A-value", and insert a formula such as this, which is checking if the value in the "whatever" column is divisible by 4, and if so, then replace a-value with b-value.

=IF(MOD(A3,4),B3,C3)

[image]

Then determine how you want to put together your final data. Copy/paste as special values into another sheet, or whatever works best for you.